# Uniqueness of a "partially-evaluated PDE"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Not sure if this sort of differential equation has a name (or if it would be considered a partial or ordinary DE or something else entirely).

Let $f(x,y)$ be an unknown real-valued function that is smooth in $y$ such that:

- $f(x,x)=1$ for all $x$
- $g(x)=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}|_{y=x}$ for some known, integrable function $g(x)$.

A solution to this equation and initial condition is clearly

$$f(x,y) = \exp\left(\int_x^y g(t) dt\right).$$

But is this solution unique? My gut tells me 'yes', but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, another solution is $$1+\int_x^y g(t)dt.$$